# java braces usage

Tags: java

I have a java code similar to this:

```
AnObject anObject = new AnObject() {
    int count;
    public int creation() {
        return count;
    }
};
```

I can't understand the meaning of the braces. A class following the constructor?
Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is an [anonymous inner class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html).

Basically, it is a subclass of `AnObject` without a name.

It's *anonymous* because it does not have a class name declaration (e.g. `class Foo`), and it is an *inner class* because it is defined within another class (which does not seem to be shown in the code provided.)

`javac` will usually name these classes with the containing class with a `$` and some numeric identifier, such as `Foobar$1` -- you'll likely find `<EnclosingClass>$1.class` after you compile that code.

*(Where `<EnclosingClass>` is the class which contains the anonymous inner class.)*

Comment: Without checking, I think you'll find a <enclosingClass>$1.class after you compile that code.

Comment: @Puce I checked and you're correct -- it is the name of the enclosing class that is used in the `class` file's name. Editing the answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

It's an anonymous inner class.

The code is almost the same as:

```
private class Foo extends AnObject {
   int count;
   public int creation() { return count; }
}
...
AnObject anObject = new Foo();
```

There are some subtle differences though:

1. The syntax is the same for extending classes and implementing interfaces.
2. Local variables of the enclosing method are visible, but only those that were declared `final`.

Answer (score 2):

It is creating an anonymous inner class.

There is some very useful tutorials on the following site about anonoymous inner classes. [Anonymous Inner class tutorials](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0100__Class-Definition/0201__Anonymous-inner-class.htm)

Answer (score 1):

This is the definition of the class. It is called an [Anonymous Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html).

Answer (score 1):

In this case the curly braces are used for creating an anonymous subclass of `AnObject`. Inside the braces are new fields and methods as methods overriding the superclass. This pattern is very common for simpler abstract classes or interfaces, such as creating a listener "in place".